# Why are react-table V8 selected reset when its tabs changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have a react-table inside a tab component and when I switch tabs the checked fields are reset, why?

[image]

My tab component:

```js
interface TabsProps {
  tabs: {
    label: string;
    index: number;
    Component: FC<{ index: number }>;
  }[];
  selectedTab: number;
  onClick: (index: number) => void;
}
/**
 * Avalible Props
 * @param tab Array of object
 * @param selectedTab number
 * @param onClick Function to set the active tab
 */
const Tabs = ({ tabs = [], selectedTab = 0, onClick }: TabsProps) => {
  const Panel = tabs && tabs.find((tab) => tab.index === selectedTab);

  return (
    <div>
      <Box marginBottom={15}>
        {tabs.map((tab) => (
          <TabButton
            className={selectedTab === tab.index ? 'active' : ''}
            onClick={() => onClick(tab.index)}
            key={tab.index}
            aria-selected={selectedTab === tab.index}
            aria-controls={`tabpanel-${tab.index}`}
            tabIndex={selectedTab === tab.index ? 0 : -1}
            id={`tab-btn-${tab.index}`}
          >
            {tab.label}
          </TabButton>
        ))}
      </Box>
      <div role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby={`btn-${selectedTab}`} id={`tabpanel-${selectedTab}`}>
        {Panel && <Panel.Component index={selectedTab} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

My table component refer [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tanstack/table/tree/main/examples/react/row-selection?from-embed=&file=/src/main.tsx:1675-1712).

I tried `autoResetAll: false` but it didn't word.

I also tried using v7:

```
  autoResetSelectedRows: false,
  autoResetSelectedCell: false,
  autoResetSelectedColumn: false,
```

but same result.